# Wifi will not connect with an Intel Wifi Link 1000

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, hp, intel-wireless, wicd

I have an HP dv7t-6100CTO laptop. I have linux ubuntu 12.04 lts dual booted. The specs of my laptop are:
- i7-2620m dual core (2.7 ghz) processor
- intel wifi link 1000 bgn wireless card

I am having a hard time getting my laptop to connect to the internet through wireless. Ethernet is fine, but at college I need wireless the majority of the time. Can anyone help?

Some steps I have done: I have tried WICD while uninstalling the Network Manager. When that didn't work, I uninstalled WICD and reinstalled Network Manager. I an not really sure what else to do.

I am having trouble with both WPA and WPA2 enterprise. I need at least one of the to work.

Comment: I have Lenovo x220 (Ubuntu 12.04) and I am not able to connect to any free wifi spots here in moscow. But it connects to my home wifi and all the wifies my friends have at their places. Indeed this is quite ridiculous, I have to connect my laptop to my android phone's shared 3G internet while there is free wifi network I can not connect to.

Comment: So many people have issues with wireless on ubuntu. Getting mine working is a requirement (I have to turn in homework from ubuntu on wireless)

Comment: This question is about Ubuntu 12.04 that is EOL and has not answers. OP has not signed on in 2 years and is unlikely to respond to any comments which are unlikely to be posted. VTC as `not reproducible`.